# Thymus & T-Cell Generation and Maturity

Tags: immunology, immunity

I am a beginner in immune system. I am trying to understand the connection between T-Cell and Thymus as person ages.

It is clear from Guyton & Hall that till teenage the T-cell from bone marrow comes to Thymus which further gets filtered so that T-Cell does not attack self antigen (normal antigen of body). In this process of filtering out T-cells about 90% of the T-cells produced in bone marrow is destroyed in Thymus.

And then its said that, after teenage Thymus gets partially inactive OR it can be removed. Now what I am unable to understand is if Thymus gets removed/inactivated, in say a 45 year old person, who is going to filter the T-cells produced in bone marrow; by filtering I mean kill off the T-cells which can attack self-antigen of body.

If anyone can throw some light, it would be great.